# how can I avoid buffer overflow in this case?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I have this exercise: "create a function in order to subtract two strings".

my attempt works just fine (with the help of an old answer here on stack overflow). The problem is that when I debug, the debugger doesn't warn me on anything, but I have a grey squiggle below the argument of malloc. visual studio says that "a sub-expression may overflow before being assigned to a wider type". This is my thought: "I need to write an if-check before malloc to make sure the sub-expression won't overflow. To do it, I've thought to do this way:
int sum = length + 1; if (condition), then do this (allocation)."
the problem is that I don't know the condition to be checked.
based on an old discussion here on stack overflow, I know that if I have a subtraction I have to do this way

```
int c = a - b; 
if (c >= a) {
// do allocation; 
} else {
return NULL; 
}
```

but it works only for subtraction, but if I have an addition this method fails.
therefore, this method doesn't work.

how can I do it?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#
char* subtract(const char* a, const char* b) {
    int a_1 = atoi(a); int b_1 = atoi(b); int result = 0; 
    result = a_1 - b_1; 
    int length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", result);
    char* str = malloc(length + 1); 
    if (str == NULL) {
        return NULL; 
    }
    snprintf(str, length + 1, "%d", result); 
    return str; 
}



int main(void) {
    char a[] = "4567"; 
    char b[] = "568"; 
    char* c; 
    c = subtract(a, b); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I do not think that the exercise is so trivial. I believe that you need to subtract any size numbers as strings for example: `"45763547657657676576576543545246547673456546453" - "34459387795438706893643389547609587984576043986754609548"`. `atoi` & `sprintf` will not help

Comment: ***How*** does that fail for addition? The `snprintf` calls should make sure you don't have a buffer overflow. Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: debuggers do not warn, debuggers help you step through code, learn to use your correctly

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm 100% sure, because this program works and I've tested it.

Comment: Well there is no addition, so I don't understand why you're talking about it.

Comment: so is this the failing code, or not? YOu are not clear

Comment: @Cheatah length + 1 is the addition I was talking about

Comment: @pm100 no, this code works, but I have a little warning. it's located in the argument of malloc, as I said.

Comment: TIL that snprintf can take a NULL pointer and tell you how big the buffer needs to be.  30 year c dev and never knew that

Comment: `malloc` expects a `size_t` type, which is unsigned. You're giving it an `int`, which is signed. It is entirely plausible you're being warned that a conversion from `int` will absolutely *not* do what you expect, especially when/if the initial `int` is actually negative.

Comment: okay, now I got it, thanks guys. should I delete the question?

Comment: If you delete it you will wasste my and other users time

Comment: `snprintf` returns a negative number if there is some error producing the formatted output string. That shouldn't happen in this case --the potential errors referred to in the man pages have to do with things like wide character values which cannot be encoded in the locale's multibyte format-- but converting a negative number to a size_t is obviously problematic. Also, if snprintf returns -1, then length+1 will be 0, which is not a valid malloc request. Resolution: check that the return value of snprintf is positive before proceeding.

Comment: If you have a build warning or error that you wonder about, then please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output (as text!) into your question, and add comments on the lines in the shown code where you get the warnings or errors. Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for how to perform arithmetic on arbitrary numbers (no matter their length) think back to basic math from school, and how you solved it using pencil and paper. You can do it just like that in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I have a little warning. it's located in the argument of malloc,
> as I said.

`malloc(length + 1);`

`length` is signed integer and it can overflow if you add 1 to it.

Solution:
cast it to `size_t`

```
malloc((size_t)length + 1);
```

***BTW***
What is the difference between "little" and "big" warnings?

**PS** How to substract `"4564536456645645645"` and `"545643563456436565436"` using your solution?

Comment: or simply declare length as size_t in the first place